# Why am I getting extra line breaks when converting HTML to text?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to formatting an HTML string to plain text. I still want to preserve the line breaks and ignore the HTML tags. But when converting I get extra empty lines and its trowing off my string.

```
String htmlString = "<p>Hello this is a description. </p><p>I know Just checking how it looks.</p><p></p><p><code>Add a line.</code></p><p>This is a notmal line <span style="color:#F9931A">Adding orange</span></p><ul><li><p>one </p></li><li><p>two</p></li></ul>";
HtmlToPlainText convert = new HtmlToPlainText();
Document html = Jsoup.parse(htmlString,"", Parser.xmlParser());
String new = convert.getPlainText(html);
System.out.println("This is the description: " + new);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hello this is a description. 

I know Just chekcing how it looks.



Add a line.

This is a notmal line Adding orange


 * one 


 * two
```

Comment: It adds a line break for each paragraph. There are extra empty paragraphs in the HTML, which is adding the extra line breaks.

Comment: I know that, but it adds an extra break right after each paragraph. ex. `<p>Hello this is a description. </p><p>I know Just checking how it looks.</p>` should be on top of each other

Comment: So how you are expecting with out space?

Comment: Try `prettyprint` false

Comment: I am not expecting two line breaks per paragraph. It should only be one from what I understand. Each paragraph is its own individual line. `prettyprint` did not work. `html.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));`